# Dynicam linear regression, lags produce NA values

Tags: r, time-series, linear-regression, ardl

How do I perform a dynlm regression when I want to included lags of both the dependent and independent variable.

For example with the following data;

```
a <- 1:10
b <- 5:15
a <- ts(a)
b <- ts(b)

dynlm(a  ~  L(a, 1:3) + L(b, 1:2))
```

What I am trying to obtain is a linear regression of the model where a depends on 3 of its own lags and 2 lags of b. However, I get NA values

I think I do not properly understand how dynlm works. Anyone who can give me some insight to what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

With respect to the data shown in the question, the intercept and first lag give a perfect prediction so the other lags are not needed.  Note that `resid(dynlm(...))` is all zero.

Comment: I do understand that. But suppose I have observation on time intervals 1 through 10. I want to regress for example observation 10 based on observation 9, 8 and 7. For example an Auto regressive model.

Comment: The question already shows how to do lags using L.  You can also use the dyn package.  If you are unclear on what regression is being run try `model.matrix(dynlm(...))` to clarify it.